# Not using band as dimension while reading raster using xarray

Tags: python, python-xarray, rasterio

I am reading in a single band raster using `xarray`. Is there a way to not have `band` be a dimension and just have the x and y coordinates as dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean directly when reading the file?

Because you can always do this after reading the file:

```
ds = ds.sel(band = 1)
```

It should return a dataset with only x and y as coords.

Comment: Or, just use `ds.squeeze()`